# Is it possible to set environment variables in Google's Colaboratory?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am running some Python scripts in Google's [Colaboratory](https://colab.research.google.com/) platform. Now, I need to set some environment variables of the system. Like the following shows:

```
!export PATH=drive/app/tf-models-fork/research;drive/app/tf-models-fork/research/object_detection;drive/app/tf-models-fork/research/slim;$PATH
```

I tried to add the location to the variable PATH. However, I am getting the following errors:

```
/bin/sh: 1: drive/app/tf-models-fork/research/object_detection: Permission denied
/bin/sh: 1: drive/app/tf-models-fork/research/slim: Permission denied
/bin/sh: 1: drive/app/tf-models-fork/research: Permission denied
```

Is there any way to set the environment variables in this platform?

Comment: The answer below suggesting `os.environ` is definitely the right approach. But if you're curious, the `export` line above is failing because you did `;` instead of `:` when appending to the existing path.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right! I will also test this correct version of "export" way. Thanks for correcting me for my mistaken!

Answer (score 17):

I normally set the `PATH` with `os.environ`, like this:

```
import os
os.environ['PATH'] += ":/usr/local/go/bin"
```

Answer (score 0):

For `PATH` environment variables, such as `PYTHONPATH`, I use `sys.path.insert` or `sys.path.append`.

You have these 2 options because `sys.path` is a list of strings (paths), thus you can either insert or append more strings.

For example,

If you want to insert a new path at index 0:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/path/to/folder')
```

If you want to append a new path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/folder')
```