# Setting environment variables in Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, kaggle

I'm trying to use the Kaggle CLI API, and in order to do that, instead of using `kaggle.json` for authentication, I'm using [environment variables to set the credentials](https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api#api-credentials).

```
!pip install --upgrade kaggle

!export KAGGLE_USERNAME=abcdefgh
!export KAGGLE_KEY=abcdefgh

!export -p
```

However, the printed list of env. variables doesn't contain the ones I set above.

```
declare -x CLICOLOR="1"
declare -x CLOUDSDK_CONFIG="/content/.config"
declare -x COLAB_GPU="1"
declare -x CUDA_PKG_VERSION="9-2=9.2.148-1"
declare -x CUDA_VERSION="9.2.148"
declare -x CUDNN_VERSION="7.4.1.5"
declare -x DATALAB_SETTINGS_OVERRIDES="{\"kernelManagerProxyPort\":6000,\"kernelManagerProxyHost\":\"172.28.0.3\",\"jupyterArgs\":[\"notebook\",\"-y\",\"--no-browser\",\"--log-level=DEBUG\",\"--debug\",\"--NotebookApp.allow_origin=\\\"*\\\"\",\"--NotebookApp.log_format=\\\"%(message)s\\\"\",\"--NotebookApp.disable_check_xsrf=True\",\"--NotebookApp.token=\",\"--Session.key=\\\"\\\"\",\"--Session.keyfile=\\\"\\\"\",\"--ContentsManager.untitled_directory=\\\"Untitled Folder\\\"\",\"--ContentsManager.untitled_file=\\\"Untitled File\\\"\",\"--ContentsManager.untitled_notebook=\\\"Untitled Notebook\\\"\",\"--KernelManager.autorestart=True\",\"--ip=\\\"172.28.0.2\\\"\"]}"
declare -x DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive"
declare -x ENV="/root/.bashrc"
declare -x GIT_PAGER="cat"
declare -x GLIBCPP_FORCE_NEW="1"
declare -x GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW="1"
declare -x HOME="/root"
declare -x HOSTNAME="2ced809e9844"
declare -x JPY_PARENT_PID="57"
declare -x LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
declare -x LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib64-nvidia"
declare -x LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcmalloc.so.4"
declare -x MPLBACKEND="module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline"
declare -x NCCL_VERSION="2.3.7"
declare -x NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES="compute,utility"
declare -x NVIDIA_REQUIRE_CUDA="cuda>=9.2"
declare -x NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="all"
declare -x OLDPWD="/"
declare -x PAGER="cat"
declare -x PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/tools/node/bin:/tools/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/opt/bin"
declare -x PWD="/content"
declare -x PYTHONPATH="/env/python"
declare -x SHELL="/bin/bash"
declare -x SHLVL="2"
declare -x TERM="xterm-color"
declare -x TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH="true"
declare -x _="/tools/node/bin/forever"
declare -x __EGL_VENDOR_LIBRARY_DIRS="/usr/lib64-nvidia:/usr/share/glvnd/egl_vendor.d/"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to set environment variables in Google Colaboratory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49684495/is-it-possible-to-set-environment-variables-in-google-colaboratory)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I think you want to do something like:

```
import os
os.environ['KAGGLE_USERNAME'] = ...
os.environ['KAGGLE_KEY'] = ...
```

The reason is that !export will assign the environment variable in an ephemeral sub-shell. But, you want to update the environment for the Python subprocess that spawns those sub-shells.

[image]

Answer (score 90):

If you like %magic, you can also use %env to make it a bit shorter.

```
%env KAGGLE_USERNAME=abcdefgh
```

If the value is in a variable you can also use

```
%env KAGGLE_USERNAME=$username
```

Comment: To set multiple env variables in one line: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26189662/how-set-multiple-env-variables-for-a-bash-command

Comment: This is just much simpler and should be the best answer

Comment: This should be THE answer!

Comment: This answer does not explain why the most obvious approach (`!export name=value`) fails.

Answer (score 1):

You could either use intput or simply getpass to set env variables.(Assuming yr using JP noteb)

```bash
!pip install getpass
```

```py
import getpass
import os


def SetEnv(name):
    secret = getpass.getpass(f"Enter value of {name}: ")
    os.environ[name] = secret

# to get var
mys = os.environ['secret']
print(mys)

# Usage to set var
SetEnv("api_id")
SetEnv("api_hash")
SetEnv("bot_token")
```