# Set permanent environment variables in Google Colab

Tags: environment-variables, google-colaboratory

How do you set environment variables in Colab that persist after a runtime restart?

I have tried:

1. Changing `~/.bashrc`

```
!echo "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64:/opt/ros/melodic/lib" >> /etc/environment
```

2. Adding line to `/etc/environment`

```
!echo "source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Questions that don't have the answer:

[Setting environment variables in Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53306150/setting-environment-variables-in-google-colab) : All methods listed here do not persist after runtime restart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it permanent, even after restart.

Just write a startup file. It will be run everytime jupyter restart. (but not if factory reset)

```py
%%file /root/.ipython/profile_default/startup/startup.py
import os
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']='/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64:/opt/ros/melodic/lib'
```

Comment: I am trying to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH with statement you have mentioned. It shows up in the env variables list ( checked from !printenv), but in my software, when I am accessing .so library which placed at LD_LIBRARY_PATH, it is not able to find it.. it works on the regular machine, but not on google code colab. Can you please help to identify what I am missing?  Thank you.