# how to add the path to PYTHONPATH in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

how to execute the following command in google colab.
`export PYTHONPATH=/project/pylib/src:$PYTHONPATH`

`!export PYTHONPATH=/project/pylib/src:$PYTHONPATH`it is not affect.

Comment: `ImportError: No module named util`

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue here. If you figured out how to do it, it would be appreciated if you can share your solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

## Edit 2020-11-12

Using `%` instead of `!` retains any changes to all cells in the session. So, we can use that to set the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`. However, export doesn't work in colab. `%env` can be used to set the environment variable.

```
! echo $PYTHONPATH
%env PYTHONPATH="$/env/python:/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/MNIST_Classifier/src"
! echo $PYTHONPATH
```

Output:

```
/env/python
/env/python:/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/MNIST_Classifier/src
```

## Initial Answer

The following worked for me

```
! echo $PYTHONPATH

import os
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] += ":/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/MNIST_Classifier/src"

! echo $PYTHONPATH
```

Output:

```
/env/python
/env/python:/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/MNIST_Classifier/src
```

Sources:
https://medium.com/@omernaeem/you-can-set-environment-variables-using-os-environ-78a5181b6376
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49684719/3337089

Comment: Worth noting, I'm using Colab in 2023 and while the updated version doesn't work for me, your initial answer does.

Answer (score 12):

The answer depends on why you want to do this.

For example, if you want to add the path to your current Python session so that Python's import mechanism finds modules located in that directory, you can do this:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, "/project/pylib/src")
```

If you want to modify the environment variable itself (which won't affect the paths used in your current Python session) you can use the `%set_env` magic:

```
%set_env PYTHONPATH=/project/pylib/src:/env/python
```

Comment: but i want to use the google colab, this environment is some different with normal system. I just want to move my project from my computer to google colab, According to my test, it can't import package with same directory in google colab, but it will work in our normal system. So i need to add PYTHONPATH.

Comment: `sys.path.insert` doesn't work for me, while `sys.path.append` does for importing packages present in the colab directory.

Answer (score 2):

In my **colab session** (tested on 8 June 2022)

```
!echo $PYTHONPATH
```

&

```
import os
os.environ['PYTHONPATH']
```

outputs `/env/python`

---

But

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

outputs

```
['', '/content', '/env/python', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', 
'/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/extensions', '/root/.ipython']
```

---

So, in scenarios where you perform `!git clone https://github.com/some_user/some_repo.git`

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, "/content/some_repo")

from some_package.utils import some_func #located in some_repo
```

will work rather than the first two options.
I added `/content/` because current working dir `!pwd` is `/content/`