# Error when running install and import from Github

Tags: python, github, package, google-colaboratory

I am using python; colab.
I tried to install package from" github.com/jleinonen/keras-fid" to import `fid`. And first time I used:

```
!pip install git+git://github.com/jleinonen/keras-fid.git
```

but I got error;

```
Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

So I used: `!git clone`
I install package from Github by using

```
!git clone https://github.com/jleinonen/keras-fid.git
```

than try to import module
However, I'm not sure but I think because package name contains "-", I got

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I import the module from this package

Comment: The SyntaxError seems unrelated to anything earlier in the question. What input did you get the syntax error for?

Comment: Merely cloning a package does not yet install the package so you can `import` it.

Comment: Probably the best fix is to figure out why the first `pip` failed; what's in the logs it tells you to look at?

Comment: This is the full log   `Collecting git+git://github.com/jleinonen/keras-fid.git`
`Cloning git://github.com/jleinonen/keras-fid.git to /tmp/pip-req-build-g8o2sz7u`
  `Running command git clone -q git://github.com/jleinonen/keras-fid.git /tmp/pip-req-build-g8o2sz7u`
`ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.'`

Comment: You need to find those logs; probably look in `/tmp/pip-req-build-g8o2sz7u`

Comment: Sorry, there is no such files.There is only `dap_multiplexer.7c266fb915c7.root.log.INFO.20210209-055750.50`, `dap_multiplexer` and `initgoogle_syslog_dir`

Comment: Quick inspection of the Github repo reveals that the error is trivial: it doesn't _have_ a `setup.py` so it can't be installed as an importable module.

Comment: Oh... I think you are right. It said there is no `setup.py`. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-` is a red herring. The problem is that the Github repo cannot be `pip install`ed because it does not contain a `setup.py`.

When you `git clone`d the code, you simply copied it to your environment. It's still not trivially installable ... though what you can do now is either add the cloned directory to your `PYTHONPATH`, or copy the file `fid.py` from inside it to somewhere which is already on your `PYTHONPATH`.

Quick demo:

```
bash$ python -c "import fid"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fid'

bash$ git clone https://github.com/jleinonen/keras-fid.git 
Cloning into 'keras-fid'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 12, done.
remote: Total 12 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 12
Unpacking objects: 100% (12/12), done.
```

Now, we have a local clone, but as you can see, it is not yet installed:

```
bash$ python -c "import fid"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fid'
```

You can add the directory name (which does contain a hyphen, but that's unproblematic here) to your `PYTHONPATH`, and then it works ... except the code contains a syntax error.

```
bash$ PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH+$PYTHONPATH:}`pwd`/keras-fid python -c "import fid"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/keras-fid/fid.py", line 134
    def __init__(self, generator, image_range=, 
                                              ^
```

I have no idea what the code is supposed to do, and I know nothing about Keras or Google Colab; but changing it to `image_range,` without an equals sign before the comma at least lets me bypass this error.

[how to add the path to PYTHONPATH in google colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56207920/how-to-add-the-path-to-pythonpath-in-google-colab) seems to have tips for how to do something similar inside Google Colab.

Comment: Submitted a bug report: https://github.com/jleinonen/keras-fid/issues/1