# Import a module in colab after gitclone

Tags: python, github, google-colaboratory

I'm having issues importing certain modules into GoogleColab after cloning them from a  Github repo.
Does anyone have any idea what the problem is and how to solve it?

After connecting my GoogleDrive with

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

and cloning the github repo

```
! git clone https://github.com/naver/dope.git
```

it appears in my colab data structure.

[Colab Data Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP2MO.png)

However, when running the actual code, I cannot import the Github modules.

```
import sys, os
import argparse
import os.path as osp
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import torch
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor

#_thisdir = osp.realpath(osp.dirname(__file__))
from dope.model import dope_resnet50, num_joints
import dope.postprocess as postprocess
import dope.visu as visu

def dope_test(imagename, modelname, postprocessing='ppi'):
    if postprocessing=='ppi':
      sys.path.append('/content/lcrnet-v2-improved-ppi')# _thisdir+'/lcrnet-v2-improved-ppi/')
      try:
        from lcr_net_ppi_improved import LCRNet_PPI_improved
      except ModuleNotFoundError:
        raise Exception('To use the pose proposals integration (ppi) as postprocessing, please follow the readme instruction by cloning our modified version of LCRNet_v2.0 here. Alternatively, you can use --postprocess nms without any installation, with a slight decrease of performance.')
```

It says

```
Import "dope.model" could not be resolved(reportMissingImports)
```

Comment: Anyone know a solution?

Comment: Do `from pprint import pp` and then show us the output of `pp(sys.path)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply `git clone`ing a library is not enough to make Python recognize it; you need to add its location to [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH), which tells your Python interpreter where to search modules for.

Let's say you have cloned the `dope` module  under `/content` directory (as the attached picture suggests).
In this case, add `/content` to [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) before importing `dope`-related stuff.

```python
import sys
sys.path.append('/content')
```

Of course, this will make Python search for other directories that resides in `/content`, such as `lcrnet-v2-improved-ppi` and `models`. To prevent this from happening, just create a directory that specifically stores Python modules, and move `dope` inside it.

---

As a side note: there is [`%env` magic command](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-env) in Colab (and underlying Jupyter Notebook and IPython), which allows users to modify environment variables. But there is [a famous trap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56227816/13301046); editing `PYTHONPATH` with `%env` has no effect on the Python interpreter that is already running, so you will still get `ImportError`!