# Google Colab Notebook seemingly not using PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am trying to train a CNN in Google Colab. My notebook is very similar to this notebook:
https://colab.research.google.com/github/AlaaSenjab/-Tutorial-Tensorflow_Object_Detection_API_On_Custom_Dataset/blob/master/weapon_detection_BL.ipynb

Mine does not have the Downloading and Orgniazing Images and Annotations, Preprocessing Images and Labels sections as I already have made my TFRecords.

I cannot figure out why, but when I run `!python3 object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py` Python says `python3: can't open file 'object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. I have correctly set up the PYTHONPATH. The directory does have the files, I did an `ls` and it has the proper files and folders.

```
!mkdir tfgit
%cd tfgit
!git clone --q https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git
# compiles the proto buffers
%cd models/research/
!protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
# exports PYTHONPATH environment var with research and slim paths
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] += ':/content/tfgit/models/research/:/content/tfgit/models/research/slim/'
```

At this point, the `PYTHONPATH` is `/env/python:/content/tfgit/models/research/:/content/tfgit/models/research/slim/`. At the same point in the linked notebook, his `PYTHONPATH` is `/env/python:/content/gun_detection/models/research/:/content/gun_detection/models/research/slim/` which is the same (ignoring the different folder names).

The next step is to run `!python3 object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py`. This runs properly in the linked notebook but in my notebook I get the `No such file or directory` error.

I've tried:

- Verifying I typed the file name correctly
- Verifying the env variable is properly set (it is)
- Factory resetting the colab notebook (twice)
- Factory resetting and then closing the tab and then opening the notebook in a new tab
- Verifying the file exists by running `!cat /content/tfgit/models/research/object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py`

Putting an echo in the same cell as the python3 line properly returns the env variable. I'm at a complete loss as to what could be wrong. As of [April 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49684495/is-it-possible-to-set-environment-variables-in-googles-colaboratory/49684719#49684719), this was the common way to set the env. variable on Google Colab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Workaround:**

This gets tensorflow working but does not fix python3 not reading the PYTHONPATH.

While in `/content/models/research`, run `pip install .` Then, run any of the scripts with their fully qualified path.

Example:

```
!python3 /content/models/research/object_detection/model_main.py \
    --pipeline_config_path=ssdlite_mobilenet_v2_coco.config\
    --model_dir=training/ \
    --alsologtostderr \
```

The script will run correctly since the module is installed.